# Como puedo crear una aplicacion para reenviar mails de una base de datos?

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-api

como andan? lo que necesito es crear una aplicacion para reenviar los mail que se mandan desde otra aplicacion y se guardan en una base de datos. Esto lo necesito porque la otra aplicacion no puede enviar los mails a @hotmail o @outlook. por ende preciso que si alguien desde la otra aplicacion manda un mail a un @hotmail esta nueva app pueda tomar el asunto, el cuerpo y el destinatario y reenviarselo. desde ya muchas gracias. soy nuevo en todo esto asi que no me linchen askaja

resumiendo, necesito un pequeño empujon para saber como empzar. que lenguaje me recomiendan y como relacionarla con la base de datos.

Comment: Desde SQL Server ya tienes esa funcionalidad. Solo hay que configurarla. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!